# SURF + BOWImgDescriptorExtractor + BFMatcher giving type error

Tags: python, opencv, surf

I am using opencv-2.4.13 with python 2.7. I am trying to create training set for my SVM classifier. In using BOWImgDescriptorExtractor I am getting type error. Here is the code..

```
extract = cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create("SURF")
surf = cv2.SURF(400)
matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_L2)

BOW = cv2.BOWKMeansTrainer(100)

for ImageName in FileList:
    img = cv2.imread(ImageName,0)
    kp, des = surf.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
    BOW.add(des)
 dictionary = BOW.cluster()

bow_extract = cv2.BOWImgDescriptorExtractor( extract, matcher ) 
bow_extract.setVocabulary( dictionary )

ImageName = FileList[0]
img = cv2.imread(ImageName,0)
kp = surf.detect(img1)
inp = bow_extract.compute(img1,kp)
```

I am getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Pre_process.py", line 48, in <module>
    inp = bow_extract.compute(img1, surf.detect(img1))
cv2.error:/opencv-2.4.13/modules/core/src/stat.cpp:2481: error: (-215) type == src2.type() && src1.cols == src2.cols && (type == CV_32F || type == CV_8U) in function batchDistance
```

Comment: could you figure it out ?

Comment: Yes.. i just added surf.extended = False .

Comment: Right after `surf = cv2.SURF(400)` or any specific position?

Comment: Yes.. Just after that.

Comment: Okay it creates now same descriptor shapes, when on the other hand I don't understand why since it just changes from 128- to 64-element descriptors

Comment: nvm I tried with different image data and I have the same error again - different descriptor shapes

Comment: May be because cv2.DescriptorExtractor_create('SURF') created descriptor extractor with 64-element. Before at the time of bow_extract.compute() it was conflicting.

Comment: I have this code running with just the correction I mentioned. I have images with various sizes. And it works well with all of them.